# Scanning for a valid integer

Tags: c, integer

Okay, total newbie here, but I need a little help/insight on how to start writing a specific program. I'm not asking for someone to do it for me, I'm just asking for an approach to this problem because I'm honestly not sure how to begin.

The program I am supposed to write is to detect valid integers. However, in this program, a valid integer is defined as the following:

- 0 or more leading white spaces followed by...
- an optional '+' or '-' followed by...
- 1 or more digits, followed by a non-alphanumeric, but not a '.' followed by 1 or more digits.

Examples of valid integers: “1234”, “ 1234 ”, “1234.”, “ +1234 ”, "12+34", "1234.", "1234 x", and “ -1234 ” are all integers, and none of “1234e5”, “e1234”, “1234.56”, and “1234abc” are.

So far, all I can think of is using a bunch of if statements to check for valid integers, but I cant help but think there has to be a better and more robust approach than using a lot of if statements to check each character of the string. I can't think of any functions that would be useful to me other than using isdigit() and maybe strtol()? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: As this looks like a Computer Science exercise, there may be boundaries to the exercise (forbidding the usage of ready made conversion functions, etc). That said, I have two words for you: regular expressions.

Comment: `man strtol`: "The string may begin with an arbitrary amount of white space (as determined by  isspace(3)) followed by a single optional '+' or '-' sign." Only non-standard procedure is to disallow clear floating point values (the leading period); but that's what its `**endptr` is for.

Comment: If it is really a cs exercise, then you should use simple code instead of regexp. So checking all characters with complex logic.

Comment: Was that list of 'valid integers' given to you? It includes "12+34", which is invalid according to your rules, unless you are supposed to parse out only the leading "12".

Comment: @Jongware yes that list of valid integers was given to me

Comment: @MarcoSandrini: Nonsense. A simple state-machine is easier and faster and does not hide part of the exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to examine each character in a loop and keep a little state machine as you're going, until you decide it's not valid or you reach the end.

Edit: Nothing wrong with if statements, or you could use a switch statement.

Comment: +1 for **not** providing a complete solution or to use regex or similar. Just to add OP should have a look at `ctype.h`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use `sscanf` (or fscanf, etc.)

Although it doesn't support full regular expressions, `scanf` format strings do support `scan set` conversions, which are about like a character set in a regular expression (including inverted ones, so for example `%1[^a-zA-Z0-9]` matches a single non-alphanumeric character).

A single space in a format string matches an arbitrary amount of white space in the input.

Comment: That sound like an excercise to generate a lexxer. using `scanf` or regexp would be bad advice.

Comment: At least to me, it looks/sounds pretty strange as an exercise. I see nothing to justify an assumption that it is (and unless you're sure it is, writing your own lexer for something scanf can do quickly and easily is just a bad idea).

Comment: You never programmed embedded systems didn't you? And even if you have  `scanf` avaliable, it is often faster and not much effort to parse on your own. Who knows? That might be to be expanded in a future step.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, I have programmed embedded systems. But his question doesn't mention anything about *either* being a homework exercise *or* having to run on a 6805 with only 256 bytes of RAM. I'm answering the question he actually asked. You seem to want an answer to a question that exists only in your own imagination.

Comment: Agree `sscanf()` could be used to solve the task - I think even a single  `sscanf()` would do it, but it is challenging, even for an experienced coder to use correctly in validation cases that do not readily match the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Put your words into code - one piece at a time.  Pseudo code follows

```
// to detect valid integers. 
success_failure detect valid integers(const char *s) {

  // 0 or more leading white spaces followed by...
  while (test_for_whitespace(*s)) s++;

  // an optional '+' or '-' followed by...
  if (test_if_sign(*s)) s++; 

  // 1 or more digits, ...
  digit_found = false;
  while (test_if_digit(*s)) { s++; digit_found = true; ]
  if (!digit_found) return fail;

  // followed by a non-alphanumeric, but not a '.' followed by 1 or more digits.
  if (is_a_non_alphanumeric_non_dp_not_null(*s)) {
    s++;
    digit_found = false;
    while (test_if_digit(*s)) { s++; digit_found = true; ]
    if (!digit_found) return fail;
  }

  if (is_not_a_null_character(*s)) return fail;
  return success;
}
```

Comment: Giving a man a fish instead of teaching him how to fish is a bad idea. Imo this is too complete already.

Comment: @Olaf Edit down to your liking.

Comment: I will certainly not. It's too late anyway, as the cat is already out of the box.

Comment: tiffyippy @Olaf & I had a minor disagreement concerning this post being too detailed.  As we all are interested in making the [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) a better place, please advise to what degree you found this answer too detailed - or possible not enough.

Comment: @chux i found the answer to be enough in detail. i've written some pseudo code out myself to try to figure out this problem and i found yours to be helpful, but not at all too informative. it helps me get the gist of the approach and thought process i should have when writing the program, but not too much information to tell me exactly how to write the program.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `strtol()`, it can tell you about invalid parts of the string by pointer return.

And beware of enthusiastic example code.. see the man page for comprehensive error-handling.

Comment: OP asks about syntax checking, not reading/converting. And `strtol` does not match the given syntax.

Comment: `strtol()` well matches the first portion of OP requirements: `WS, sign, digits`